# Form 'select' option passing extra value in IE7 and IE8

Tags: jquery, html, forms, internet-explorer

I'm passing expiry parameters with a form 'select' option.  Works in all browsers except for IE7 and IE8.  Below is the form snippit and received array from the card processor logs.  Notice an extra '0' is passed for each option.

```
                    <div class="form-row expiry">
                        <label>Card Expiration (ex. 01/2015)</label>
                        <select class="card-expiry-month required" type="text">
                                <option value="">Month</option>
                                <option value="01">01 January</option>
                                <option value="02">02 February</option>
                                <option value="03">03 March</option>
                                <option value="04">04 April</option>
                                <option value="05">05 May</option>
                                <option value="06">06 June</option>
                                <option value="07">07 July</option>
                                <option value="08">08 August</option>
                                <option value="09">09 September</option>
                                <option value="10">10 October</option>
                                <option value="11">11 November</option>
                                <option value="12">12 December</option>
                            <select/>
                        <select class="card-expiry-year required" type="text">
                                <option value="">Year</option>
                                <option value="2012">2012</option>
                                <option value="2013">2013</option>
                                <option value="2014">2014</option>
                                <option value="2015">2015</option>
                                <option value="2016">2016</option>
                                <option value="2017">2017</option>
                                <option value="2018">2018</option>
                            <select/>
                    </div>
```

Here is the unsuccessful log from the card processor.

```
   "request_id": "1333070804570",
   "card": {
   "number": "************4242",
   "exp_year": {
      "0": "2014"
    },
   "exp_month": {
      "0": "2"
    },
   "cvc": "***"

 }
```

A successful log from the same form in chrome.

```
"card": {
"cvc": "***",
"number": "*******************0002",
"exp_month": "02",
"exp_year": "2013"
  },
"request_id": "1333070383437"
 }
```

Comment: Am I missing something, or are you missing a `name` or `id` attribute in the `select` tags?  Can you post the entire form?  And can you provide more information about how you are getting the data from the form to the card processor?  (How are you parsing the data before you send it to the processor?)

Comment: The link you provided results in a 404 for me.  Nevermind - you fixed it.

Comment: BTW, 4242424242424242 with any 3 digit cvc passes the Luhn check for testing.

Comment: What does the `type="text"` do for you in the `select` tag?  Is that supposed to be there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why type="text" is used on a select element. You have some nesting issues as well, the empty `<select/>` element should be the end tag: `</select>`.